# Showing 1900px page on 1024px screen

Tags: browser

I have a 1900px-wide web page at https://zackel.com/50/a0.html that I'd like to display as intelligently as I can on smaller screens, say 1024 x 768.  If you show the page now on a 1024-wide screen the left side is cut off and there's no scroll bar to go over and see it.

I've been using

http://www.infobyip.com/testwebsiteresolution.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fzackel.com%2F50%2Fa0.html&width=1024&height=768&in_browser=true

to view the page on various screens.

How can I get browsers to scroll over to the left to see the Box 1 and Box 2 content there?

Or what do I have to do to the HTML/CSS to get it to adjust on load to a smaller screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a responsive/fluid width design , also if by chance you are using firefox , you can change the resolution of your browser window by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+M

Couple of responsive HTML5 frameworks that might be of help to you --

- http://foundation.zurb.com/
- http://getbootstrap.com/